# What's a better way to handle errors for Get-SPWeb?

Tags: 2010, powershell, error-handling

I've noticed my favorite `trap`s don't work as intended when attempting to get an SPWeb object.

Example:

```
trap { write-host "an error occurred. continue."; continue } & { nonexistant_command }
```

returns

```
an error occurred. continue.
```

But

```
trap { write-host "an error occurred. continue."; continue } & { Get-SPWeb blarg }
```

returns a much nastier

```
Get-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following Id or Url: dsoijfsd.
At line:1 char:75
+ trap { write-host "an error occurred. continue."; continue } & { Get-SPWeb <<<<  dsoijfsd }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletGetWeb:SPCmdletGetWeb) [Get-SPWeb], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetWeb
```

Is there a way to retrieve this error (using `trap`, `try-catch`, etc), without missing it entirely or simply ignoring it?

Comment: what you want, get the error or skip the error?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I'd like to get the error without skipping it. :P

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This will get the SPWeb object and continue whether or not it finds anything.

Answer (score 0):

try...catch work well in PowerShell, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx which has a great write up for try catch finally, and other items around error handling.

for example (from link)

```
try
{
    <#
        Add dangerous code here that might produce exceptions.
        Place as many code statements as needed here.
        Non-terminating errors must have error action preference set to Stop to be caught.
    #>

    write-host "Attempting dangerous operation"
    $content = get-content -Path "C:\SomeFolder\This_File_Might_Not_Exist.txt" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    <#
        You can have multiple catch blocks (for different exceptions), or one single catch.
        The last error record is available inside the catch block under the $_ variable.
        Code inside this block is used for error handling. Examples include logging an error,
        sending an email, writing to the event log, performing a recovery action, etc.
        In this example I'm just printing the exception type and message to the screen.
    #>

    write-host "Caught an exception:" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
finally
{
    <#
        Any statements in this block will always run even if errors are caught.
        This statement block is optional. Normally used for cleanup and
        releasing resources that must happen even under error situations.
    #>

    write-host "Finally block reached"
}
```

Comment: `try{Get-SPWeb 'fail'} catch { Write-Host "caught an error" } finally { write-host "Finally reached."}`  --  This will not catch the error, but the finally block will run. I think something here is beyond try-catch...

Comment: Give this a whirl `try {
 Get-SPWeb 'fail' -ErrorAction 'Stop' 
} catch { 
 Write-Host "caught an error"
} 
finally { 
 write-host "Finally reached."
}`

Comment: the change being adding -ErrorAction 'Stop' after the get-spweb